# Passing token to angular app in IOS webview

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webview

I am trying to figure out how to handle passing a token to an angular web app running in a webview.
 In the IOS app when the user clicks a button it opens the webview loading the angular app. To populate the angular app with data we need to get the users token. I want to avoid a login screen/process so I am trying to send the token from the IOS app. All requests to the API are done using this token. Currently the IOS side is sending the token in the header and i'm wondering how to capture the token with angular and store it somewhere so I can make the further calls to the API using the token. 
 The angular app is running on an express server which really only passes requests along

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();

app.use(express.static('www'));

// CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) headers to support Cross-site HTTP requests
app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
    console.log(req.header);
    next();
}); 
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 5000);

app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

So can I grab the token with angular or should I be doing this with express and somehow passing this along? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to call a ad-hoc javascript function from webView

Implement the UIWebView's delegate method `webViewDidFinishLoad:` in your UIViewController and in there you call `[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"setToken('your_token')"];`

If you are using the Cordova framework you could use [cordova-broadcaster-plugin](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.bsc.cordova.broadcaster)

Comment: Thanks, that works well. We preload the page, set the token and then angular can use it across the app.